# Has anyone tried building an ASP.NET Session State Provider for Amazon SimpleDB?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, session-state, amazon-simpledb

If not, are there any fundamental limitations of the service that prevent one from being built?

Comment: Going across the Internet to obtain your session state? Seems like a recipe for slow to me.

Comment: I would couple simpleDB with a local caching strategy and I think it would make a good session state provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [C# library](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1133) for working with SDB.

If you want to roll your own, the API, WSDL and other documentation can be found at http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/#resources.

It's a pretty straight forward API that rides over HTTP. The hardest part is writing the signing code. There's plenty of implementations in other languages.

As for using it for session state, there's a huge speed difference between using SimpleDB from EC2 and anywhere else on the internet. If you're hosting your app on EC2, it'll be fine, otherwise, it'll be brutally slow.

Comment: The "C# library" link is dead. Plus if you want to use the Amazon library you should be using the Amazon SDK for .NET, not the old SimpleDB-only library. The SDK is here: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/

Answer (score 4):

In response to Garys answer. "If you're hosting your app on EC2, it'll be fine"

Even if you're hosting your application on EC2 you should not really use SimpleDB to store session state. It provides an "eventually consistent" guarantee, so if you PUT something there is no guarantee that you will see the item on your next GET.

see: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/2007-11-07/DeveloperGuide/index.html?EventualConsistencySummary.html

This is fine when you want to use simpledb to do indexing on data that does not need to be immediately up to date and can be reconciled later, but in the case of session state, you'd likely want something with ACID guarantees (like SQL Server) as you want to know that once you have committed something you will get it back on the next read.

This obviously depends on your requirements, but most people use session state to store shopping cart items or similar. Your site visitors will soon get upset if things appear to go missing from thier cart, then re-add them and then discover they have added the same item twice when they come to pay.

Comment: Just noticed this answer and wanted to update - SimpleDB now allows for consistent reads and writes and is probably a very suitable and scalable candidate for session state provider IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You could base it off this MySQL provider:

http://harry-kimpel.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!CAA619CB4C4D1B6C!342.entry